# How can I get correct order in Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why my dictionary object cannot show as correct order.

```
 with open("data.txt", "r") as data:
    for line in data:
        json_line = json.loads(line.strip())
        if json_line["Product_ID"] == id:
            return jsonify(json_line), 200
```

Original order is

```
{"Product_ID": "010", "Product_dec": "orange", "price": 21, "Quantity": 2}
```

But the output is

```
{"Product_ID": "010", "Product_dec": "orange", "Quantity": 2, "price": 21}
```

Comment: Python dictionaries aren't ordered data structures. Why does the order matter here anyway?

Comment: What version of python are you using in generally dicts are not ordered. In later python versions they hold their order. Alternativly you can use ordered dict from the collection library

Comment: Hello, I think these answers may be useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared), basically in python 3.6 and above dict isn't ordered.

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili in newer versions it _does_ retain insertion order, but it's still not _semantically_ ordered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

Comment: Sidenote: [`id` is a bad variable name](/q/77552/4518341). You could use `product_id` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a python version newer than 3.6 the only thing you need to do is to set the `JSON_SORT_KEYS` for Flask on `False`:

```
app.config["JSON_SORT_KEYS"] = False
```

For older python version you will need to use the `json.loads` like this:

```
json_line = json.loads(line.strip(), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Bellow is a code very similar with yours which shows the above points:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from collections import OrderedDict

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["JSON_SORT_KEYS"] = False

with app.app_context():

    with open("D:/data.txt", "r") as data:
        for line in data:
            json_line = json.loads(line.strip(), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
            print(json_line)
            if json_line["Product_ID"] == '010':
                a = jsonify(json_line), 200
                print(a[0].json)
```

Comment: It's work! Thanks!